# How to change list of string to list of elements (numbers)?

Tags: python, csv, txt

When I use:

```
with open("test.txt") as file
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for i in read:
        print(i)
```

and I have got something like that:

```
['[0', ' 0', ' 1', ' 0]']
```

and I need:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Any advises please?

Comment: Use int() to cast to integer. Use replace() to remove the '[]'

Comment: Seems like your file is not a CSV file. Can you share sample content it has?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  That is not a CSV file.  The file had Python lists written to it as strings.  Fix the file to write a true CSV, or use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string back into a Python list.

Comment: Thanks for help! But I already solve my problem, taking into consideration answers below.

Comment: Still, they would not be the optimal answers if you would explain more about your context. Is the file really a CSV file? Or is it JSON? Or still something else?

Comment: It was txt file, `with open("statistics_test.txt") as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for stat in read:
        statistics = [int(stat[0][1:]), int(stat[1]), int(stat[2]), int(stat[3][:2])]` It's working like I want

Answer (score 0):

```
ad = ['[0', ' 0', ' 1', ' 0]']
for i in range(len(ad)):
    ad[i] = int(ad[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
print ad
[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for help! But I already solve my problem, taking into consideration all answers. @Ragu Ram

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the easiest solution would be a list comprehension where `new = [int(a) for a in old]`. However, in your case, the first and last elements of your list actually have brackets inside of them too.

Instead, you need to do something like:

```
new = [int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, a))) for a in old]
```

This is a pretty big one liner so lets break it down.

1. The list comprehension iterates through each element in your list (I called it `old`) and names it `a`
2. A is passed into the `filter` command with the function `str.isdigit`. This basically removes any character that isn't a digit. The issue with this, is that it returns an iterator and not a simple value.
3. To fix the iterator problem, I wrapped the filter command with a `"".join()` command to convert it to a simple string value. This string will only have the number.
4. Finally, we can wrap that entire thing with the `int` command which will transform your value into an int.

If you don't like the one-liner, it can also be done this way:

```
new = []
for a in old:
    filtered = filter(str.isdigit, a)
    num_str = "".join(filtered)
    num.append(int(num_str))
```

It's the same thing but a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thanks for help! But I already solve my problem, taking into consideration all answers. @Akilan Manivannan

Answer (score 0):

```py
def parseToInt(s): 
    ...:     return int((s.replace('[', '')).replace(']', ''))
```

```py
list(map(lambda x: parseToINt(x), a))
```

Comment: Thanks for help! But I already solve my problem, taking into consideration all answers. @Alex